# parse_dates in all the columns (unspecified number) when using pd.read_csv

Tags: pandas, csv, python-datetime

I am reading data from a csv file that contains a multilevel index and a number of columns with dates. The number of columns will change over time. How can I parse all of those dates if I don't know the number of columns or the names of the columns?

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[what_do_I_put_here?], dayfirst=True, index_col=[0,1,2,3])
```

How would you solve it? If I don't parse the dates, they come as "object" instead of datetime64, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the file line by line until it reaches the end. And on each line change you change a counter.

Try something like this (it is written in C not python.):

```
for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
        count++;
```

Comment: Thank you @Zach. I'm looking for a Python solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own challenge by not parsing the dates when reading the csv file and converting them later. See code below.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=0, index_col=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df = df[:].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```